# .Net Prevents API Web Service Connection

Tags: c#, web-services, authentication, ssl, certificate

I have created an app in C# (.exe output) which connects to an API WebService that requires  a Self-Signed certificate.

For debugging, I have add the certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities certificate store, and It has been working perfectly.

Running it from command line console, I do not get any error neither, (I guess it is because of command line also checks if the certificate is there.)

The problems comes when the applications is runn from another process, then is when I get the following error.

"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

My questions are:

- Why can I run it without any problem from comand line and from an automated process dont??
- What should I do in order to that my application would use the self-signed certificate?

**I have found the solution.**

[System.Net.WebException thrown when consuming a web service over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552598/system-net-webexception-thrown-when-consuming-a-web-service-over-https)

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention it, but is the process running as another user?

Unless you specifically select the computer account certificate store, you'll add certificates to your personal certificate store (your user account). These are not available when running as another user.

To make a certificate available for all users, add it to the computer certificate store:

1. Start mmc.exe
2. Press CTRL+M (Add/remove snap-in)
3. Select Certificates, click Add
4. Select Computer account, click Finish
5. Import your certificate

You can also select Service account and select the service which needs access to the certificate if you prefer.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788967.aspx) article on MSDN covers the same steps and is a bit more verbose.

Edit:

Adding a certificate to the machine store requires elevated permissions. If you're not bundling this in a MSI installer, I suggest you write a separate InstallCertificate.exe (console or windows app) which performs the installation.

In Visual Studio:

Create a new console/windows application and add an Application Manifest File (Add Item / CTRL+SHIFT+A). In the app.manifest file just added, change this line

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

into this

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Place this code in Program.cs (add some logging and error handling before pushing this to production!):

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace InstallCertificate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cerFileName = args[0];
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(cerFileName);
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            store.Add(certificate);
            store.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Run the application. You should get the UAC prompt and the certificate should be installed in your machine's root cert store.

Comment: Yes! I think you are right because the process which run my App is logged as another user. Then, is it possible to program your solution to my code with .Net?